# Immer produce inside rxjs stream can't operate on object

Tags: javascript, rxjs, immer.js

I have a rxjs stream where I want to modify the data moving through the stream with immer's produce.

I combine two observables of an action type:

> Action<T, Type extends string = string> is a type of object that
> represents an event. It has a type property and a payload property.

For context I am using [state-adapt](https://state-adapt.github.io/docs/core#action) for state management and this is where the action type comes from

So i have declared the following stream:

```js
  private addNoteRowToSessionSegmentEffect$ = combineLatest([
    this.segmentStateChangeAction$,
    this.setActiveSessionAction$,
  ]).pipe(
    filter(
      ([noteAction]) =>
      noteAction.payload.action === cellActionsEnum.Enum["TOGGLE-NOTE"]
    ),
    switchMap(([noteAction, sessionAction]) => {
      console.log('session type', typeof sessionAction.payload) // logs 'session type object'
      console.log('session', sessionAction.payload) // logs 'Observable {_subscribe: ƒ}'
      return of(
        produce(sessionAction.payload, draftSession => {
          draftSession.title = noteAction.payload.action;
        })
      );
    }),
    toSource("[FEAT SESSION] add note effect")
  );
```

The problem is I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [Immer] produce can only be called on things that are
> draftable: plain objects, arrays, Map, Set or classes that are marked
> with '[immerable]: true'. Got '[object Object]'

immer produce works on plain objects but not on observables.  I thought that the values inside the switchMap (**noteAction** and **sessionAction**) would represent the plain objects of the observable data, but it looks like the observable itself is getting passed into the produce function.

If I console log the value of **sessionAction.payload** I get ***Observable {_subscribe: ƒ}*** instead of a plain object {...}

I am looking for direction on how to get the plain object represented by the observable in the switchMap function.

Comment: If you get type Observable when you log `sessionAction.payload`, that means you're probably passing an observable when you fire that action.  Also, instead of using `switchMap` & `of`, you can simply just use `map` [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-f4znwp?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts)

Comment: @BizzyBob thanks for the reply, this pipeline is inside a declarative state management service.  So you are right, an observable is kicking off the action and is the payload being passed through the stream.  Is there a way to extract the plain object represented by the observable inside the map/switchmap so that I can pass the required plain object to immer's produce function?

Comment: Sure, something like [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ukzt62?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts) should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sectionAction payload is actually an observable, then you need to unwrap it.  Something like this should work:

```js
private addNoteRowToSessionSegmentEffect$ = combineLatest([
  this.segmentStateChangeAction$,
  this.setActiveSessionAction$,
]).pipe(
  filter(([noteAction]) => noteAction.payload.action === cellActionsEnum.Enum["TOGGLE-NOTE"]),
  switchMap(([noteAction, sessionAction]) => sessionAction.payload.pipe(
    map(sessionActionPayload => produce(sessionActionPayload, draftSession => {
      draftSession.title = noteAction.payload.action;
    }))
  )),
  toSource("[FEAT SESSION] add note effect")
);
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ukzt62?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts)